# What's that flower!

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

Does anyone know what kind of flower this is? Thanks

Comment: Can we see more of the plant - are there any leaves out of shot? What we can see is well past its best, looks like they've been caught by cold... and its impossible to tell size and growth habit (could be a vine or a large or small shrub, can't tell) from this picture

Comment: Welcome Marty! For identification questions, more detailed information is important. [Here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) are the guidelines. @Bamboo already asked for more pictures. Would you also answer her other questions? What is the location of the plant and the temperature range? To add information, press the gray word "edit." The question will open and you can put it there. I invite you to visit our [help]. If you have questions about how to do anything, just leave us a note! We're here to help!

Answer (score 4):

It is an orchid - Brassavola cucullata

Here is a short article from the [American Orchid Society](http://www.aos.org/orchids/collectors-items/brassavola-cucullata.aspx), copied below in case the link fails at some time in the future...

> Weird and wonderful, Brassavola cucullata will add a conversation
>   piece to any collection of orchids. Visitors often comment, "that's an
>   orchid?". B. cucullata is the type species for the genus, yet unique
>   with its fringed lip with its long, tapered tip. The species passed
>   through several genera since it was first known as Helleborine
>   floribus albis, cucullatis Plum. (1703) based on a drawing of a plant
>   from Haiti. In 1813 this species was used by R. Brown to establish the
>   genus Brassavola.
>
> This orchid can be found in the West Indies, Mexico, Central America
>   and Colombia, Trinidad, Guyana and Venezuela. As might be expected
>   with such a widely distributed species, it can be adapted to a wide
>   range of cultural environments and generally, is easy to grow. One
>   would also expect such a widely distributed species to display
>   considerable variation in flowers. Surprisingly B. cucullata produces
>   relatively consistent flowers regardless of where the plants originate
>   from. The biggest difference one sees from plant to plant is in the
>   color of the flowers. Although generally concolor white, flowers can
>   have more or less golden petals and sepals and I have seen some
>   examples that have almost reddish flowers. I suspect that these
>   colorful variations might be as much due to cultural factors as
>   genetics because the same plant can produce white flowers one year,
>   and golden ones the next. In any event, there is usually more color on
>   the outside surfaces of the flowers than the insides and the color
>   tends to darken as the flowers age.

Comment: Cool. I knew it was an orchid and the flower looked like a Brassia, but I wasn't sure of the actual plant.

Comment: @Dalton yeah based on the flower shape Brassia was my first guess too, but the pencil like leaves gave it away for me.

Comment: I'm not good with the names and with the way they change them, I don't even really try. I've tried multiple species, but I have trouble with anything outside the oncidium types. It's because I have to bring them into a low humidity home in the winter. Though I have gotten a phal to bloom for the first time ever this year and it bloomed twice. Turns out my definition of low light and theirs are pretty different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an orchid to me. Can't be more specific, but I saw similar plants in the Chicago's Lincoln Conservatory a couple of months ago in their Orchid room.